# Play individually split video files in android

Tags: android

I'm working on an android project which needs me to split a video file into some parts(like each of 5 mb) and then individually playing these parts. I have successfully split the video into the parts but these parts are not playing.(maybe missing some playing attributes identified by the player). If someone could provide the solution as to how to play these individual parts without merging(necessary for my project) in context of code only. ps. cannot use any third party software as making an android app.

### code:-

```
public static void splitFile(File f) {
    int partCounter = 1;//I like to name parts from 001, 002, 003, ...
    //you can change it to 0 if you want 000, 001, ...

    int sizeOfFiles = 1024 * 1024 * 10;// 10MB
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfFiles];

    try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(f))) {//try-with-resources to ensure closing stream
        String name = f.getName();

        int tmp = 0;
        while ((tmp = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            //write each chunk of data into separate file with different number in name
            File newFile = new File(f.getParent(), name + "."
                    + String.format("%03d", partCounter++)+".mp4");
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile)) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, tmp);//tmp is chunk size
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### splitting files:

```
[ /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.001, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.002, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.003, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.004, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.005, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.006, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.007, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.008 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FFMPEG library to split video. your splitting method might be damage video. This will not happened with FFMPEG

ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -acodec copy -f segment -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 OUTPUT%d.mp4

Comment: can you please send me that libaray

Comment: it's spliting the video files?

Comment: it's just basic set up of FFMPEG library, For split video you has to fire command. you need to research about how to fire command

Comment: i want to splitting the files as some parts

Comment: you can do it using following command ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -acodec copy -f segment -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 OUTPUT%d.mp4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143259/discussion-between-krish-and-rajesh).